# Is there a less memory extensive or more efficient way of merging MP3 than file_get_contents?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, file-io

I need to merge several mp3 files into one.

I am currently doing this:

```
$combinedFiles = "";
$dir = $_POST['dir'];

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $combinedFiles .= file_get_contents(urldecode($dir."/".$entry));
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}


file_put_contents("mp3/".$dir.".mp3",   ($combinedFiles));
```

If I do:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

it works. I have tried setting this limit to 4MB, and it doesn't throw memory errors, but the file doesn't get created. Without setting any limit and leaving the default, I get allocation memory errors. I don't want to leave it at `-1` as I have read it is bad practice and can lead to problems.

Thank you (the error doesn't come from anywhere else in the code, I am running that only).

Edit: Even setting to 8GB, which is my computers memory, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach?

```
<?php
$dir = $_POST['dir'];

if ($handle = opendir($dir))
{
    $outFd = fopen(sprintf("mp3/%s.mp3", $dir), 'wb');

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..")
        {
            $path = urldecode(sprintf("%s/%s", $dir, $entry));

            $inFd = fopen($path, 'rb');
            stream_copy_to_stream($inFd, $outFd);
            fclose($inFd);
        }
    }

    fclose($outFd);

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Now, we have some security concerns with not properly validating input, and if this is a public tool, you should fix them. But for now I'll just discuss the problem at hand.

Instead of storing the data from all of these files in memory at once, why don't we just open the output file first, then copy each input file to the end of the output file? We can do this with [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php).

We could use a smaller chunk size for the operation as well via [`stream_set_chunk_size()`](https://secure.php.net/stream_set_chunk_size), but it sounds like, for your application, that it would be okay to store one MP3 in memory temporarily (4-5Mb tops). You could also just read / write a chunk at a time manually rather than using `stream_copy_to_stream()`, but the general idea is the same.

This should result in less than one file being actually stored in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), it worked for me a couple of times

Answer (score 1):

In your example you copy all files to memory and write them back to disk when the job is done.

My advice:

1. Copy the first file to the new location
2. Get the contents from the second file and append it to the copied file (file_put_contens FILE_APPEND)
3. Unset the variable with the content
4. continue with step 2 until it's done

Comment: Thanks, this works wonderfully. Too bad i cannot have two accepted answers. I will stick with this one as it is more similar to my original approach